# PFC related question regarding SQRT(6)

Tags: power-factor-correction

I am building a PFC using a TI C2000, this is for a final project and currently reading lots of datasheets on the subject.  I have a question regarding a calculation used on a **On Semiconductor** Application Note AND9062/D, full PDF is [here](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/AND9062-D.PDF).  This gives some calculations and steps for the inductor sizing as well as losses due to the mosfet and recovery diode.

The extract I am having trouble with is regarding the use of the below formulae in equation 4, which uses the SQRT(6).  Why SQRT(6)?

[image]

Regards,

Ant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ratio of peak to RMS for the sine is 1/\$\sqrt{2}\$. Ratio for triangle is 1/\$\sqrt{3}\$. I think the waveform you are dealing with is a triangle wave within a sine envelope, hence the product of the two factors.

https://www.fairchildsemi.com.cn/Assets/zSystem/documents/collateral/onlineSeminars/Understanding-Interleaved-Boundary-Conduction-Mode-PFC-Converters-WP.pdf  Fig 2 looks pertinent.

Comment: Gwideman, thanks for the answer and the link will have a read of the PDF.  Looks like the use of SQRT(6) is specific to the NCP1611 PFC integrated circuit the application note describes then, will read more into the NCP1611 as well.

Comment: I'm not sure how relevant the PDF is. I know next to nothing about this subject, but the ratios fit Figure 2 of that paper, so that's why I think the triangle x sine is the answer to "why \$\sqrt{6}\$".

Comment: That's fine I didn't know 1/SQRT(3) was for a triangle wave, so gives me an area to research.